# Impersonation in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, impersonation

I have an Action that needs to read a file from a secure location, so I have to use impersonation to read the file.

This code WORKS:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult DirectDownload(Guid id)
{
    if (Impersonator.ImpersonateValidUser())
    {
        try
        {
            var path = "path to file";
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                return View("filenotfound");
            }

            var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            return File(bytes, "application/octet-stream", "FileName");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Exception(e);
        }finally
        {
            Impersonator.UndoImpersonation();
        }
    }
    return View("filenotfound");
}
```

The only problem with the above code is that I have to read the entire file into memory and I am going to be dealing with VERY large files, so this is not a good solution.  But if I replace these 2 lines:

```
var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
return File(bytes, "application/octet-stream", "FileName");
```

with this:

```
return File(path, "application/octet-stream", "FileName");
```

It does NOT work and I get the error message:

> Access to the path
>   'c:\projects\uploads\1\aa2bcbe7-ea99-499d-add8-c1fdac561b0e\Untitled
>   2.csv' is denied.

I guess using the File results with a path, tries to open the file at a later time in the request pipeline when I have already "undone" the impersonation.

Remember, the impersonation code works because I can read the file in the bytes array.  What I want to do though is stream the file to the client.

Any idea how I can work around this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try writing a custom `FilePathResult`:

```
public class ImpersonatingFileResult : FilePathResult
{
    public ImpersonatingFileResult(string fileName, string contentType) 
        : base(fileName, contentType)
    { }

    protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        // TODO : Start impersonation
        response.TransmitFile(FileName);
        // TODO : Rollback impersonation
    }
}
```

and in your controller:

```
return new ImpersonatingFileResult(path, "application/octet-stream");
```

Comment: That worked great.  I changed it a little because I was getting an exception...  Impersonator.ImpersonateValidUser();            response.WriteFile(FileName);             response.Flush();
            response.End();             Impersonator.UndoImpersonation();

Comment: Yes, this is a good start.  However, it will throw "Invalid Handle" errors in certain versions of IIS, which are based on serving up the file (and not based on the impersonation.)

Answer (score 2):

I like **Darin's answer**, but it skips the impersonation logic, and it throws an error in IIS 7...

So, I added the impersonation code as you could by utilizing **Nuget Package SimpleImpersonation**.

Also, a couple changes were thrown in for IIS 7 to prevent an invalid handle error.

```
public class ImpersonatingFileResult : FilePathResult
{
    public ImpersonatingFileResult(string fileName, string contentType)
        : base(fileName, contentType)
    { }

    protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        using (SimpleImpersonation.Impersonation.LogonUser(domain: "SomeDomain", username: "SomeUser", password: "SomePassword", logonType: SimpleImpersonation.LogonType.NewCredentials))
        {
            response.Clear();
            response.ContentType = base.ContentType;
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(base.FileName));
            response.TransmitFile(FileName);
            response.Flush();
        }
    }
```

And then using it from controller:

```
        return new ImpersonatingFileResult(someFilePath, "Application/pdf");
```

The above is for downloading the file, but if you want to display it, then you need to specify "inline".

```
            response.Clear();
            response.ContentType = base.ContentType;
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(base.FileName) + "\"");
            response.TransmitFile(FileName);
            response.Flush();
```