# FilePathResult with network path throws COMException (The handle is invalid)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, networking, comexception

I am using the FilePathResult like so:

```
return new FilePathResult(path, "text/xml");
```

My path is a path elsewhere on our network.  This results in a server error.  When I check the event log on the server I can see this error entry:

```
TransmitFile failed. File Name: \\our\path\to\the\file\filename.dfxp, HRESULT: 0x80070005
```

At the same time a warning is logged in the event viewer as well:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 5/30/2013 4:05:03 PM 
Event time (UTC): 5/30/2013 9:05:03 PM 
Event ID: d77e5b799b87455f9f4daa7367f1bad2 
Event sequence: 33 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT-1-130144212630349792 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\my.site.folder\ 
    Machine name: MyMachine

Process information: 
    Process ID: 3408 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\my.site.name

Exception information: 
    Exception type: COMException 
    Exception message: The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://my.site.com/Download/fca4fd06-d942-4ee8-8fe3-7ec7aa26938f 
    Request path: /Download/fca4fd06-d942-4ee8-8fe3-7ec7aa26938f 
    User host address: 10.0.70.17 
    User: my@user.com
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Forms 
    Thread account name: OURDOMAIN\SA-ACCOUNT

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 14 
    Thread account name: OURDOMAIN\SA-ACCOUNT
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:
```

My service account that the application is running under has read access to the folder location.  I didn't find this problem mentioned elsewhere in the ASP.NET MVC world so I thought I would ask here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be too early to tell, however, it seems as though changing from a `FilePathResult` to a `FileContentResult` has fixed the problem.

```
var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfo.FullName);
return new FileContentResult(fileBytes, "text/xml")
```

I'm not sure what FilePathResult ends up doing internally, but, reading the file with `ReadAllBytes` seems to avoid the issue.

Comment: ReadAllBytes reads the entire file into memory, not good with large files. This solution does not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645302/impersonation-in-asp-net-mvc